# is there a way to find if an object in an array has been destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to figure out a way to detect if a Gameobject in an array is destroyed, but I haven't come remotely close to figuring this out.

Is there a way to do this or is it just plan imposable?

Comment: Please be careful not to  misuse tags. Most tags have descriptions that you can read by hovering over them, and the descriptions usually outline cases where you should or shouldn't use the tags. For example, the `[visual-studio]` question should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application, as opposed to code authored within the VS environment. I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: how about `gameobject == null `

Comment: `using System.Linq;` and `if(yourGameObjectArray.Any(g => !g)){ Debug.Log("One of the objects has been destroyed"); }`